# Swift - Loop through different object types

Tags: ios, swift

Current I do this to loop through all of my buttons:

```
for objects in view.subviews {
    if let object = objects as? UIButton {
        object.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Can I also include `UIView` and `UILabel` in this loop?

So instead of only `objects as? UIButton`, I want `objects as? UIButton, UIView, UILabel`.

Comment: You could make a protocol describes what you're trying to do, e.g. `Disableable`, and conform all the types you want to that protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
for objects in view.subviews {
    if let object = objects as? UIButton {
        object.isEnabled = false
    }
    if let object = objects as? UIView {
        object.isHidden = false
    }
    if let object = objects as? UILabel {
        object.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIControl` and `UIView` is probably all you need.

Comment: `switch object { case let button as UIButton }` would be a bit nicer. Also note that you need to use `else-if` otherwise you are just hiding everything as `UIView`.

Comment: @Sulthan Well this answer made it work perfectly, so.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't set the `isEnabled` property of labels and other `UIViews`. Only objects that inherit from `UIControl` have the `isEnabled` property.

I would advise against looping through all a view's subviews and disabling all the controls. It is a very "shotgun" approach, and fragile.

A problem with it is that it won't work if you have any complexity to your view hierarchy. If you have buttons in a stack view, for example, your code would miss them. Or say they are in a table view. That won't work either.

Instead, I would suggest putting the outlets of the controls you want to disable into an array in your `viewDidLoad()` method. Then when you want to disable them all, loop through that array and set `isEnabled` to false for each.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to assign tags to the relevant UI elements.

In the loop (or `forEach` closure) check if the tag is in the required range and conditional downcast the view to `UIControl`

```
view.subviews.forEach{ subView in
    guard (100...105).contains(subView.tag) else { return }
    (subView as? UIControl)?.isEnabled = false
}
```